# GMOD LUA - Freeze and force switch to "keys"

Tags: lua

(Code for a gmod DarkRP server)

So I wanted to edit the physgun script which freezes players ( found [here](https://forums.ulyssesmod.net/index.php?topic=8265.0)) so that it also forces players to "keys" when you pick them up (when their griefing or killing players)
Should be pretty easy yet the script just doesn't work...
Anyone have any idea's or tips ? Already tried putting the code in autorun and server autorun.
Thanks!

ps. 
First post, sorry if I did something wrong

```html
function GODMODE( ply, dmginfo) if(ply:GetNWInt("GOD") == 1) then
        dmginfo:ScaleDamage(0)
    end

hook.Add("EntityTakeDamage", "GODMODE", GODMODE)
    end

hook.add("PhysgunDrop", "ply_physgunfreeze", function(ply, ent)
    hook.Remove("PhysgunDrop", "ulxPlayerDrop")

    ent._frozen = false if( ent:IsPlayer()) then
        ent.SetMoveType(ply:KeyDown(IN_ATTACK2) and MOVETYPE_NOCLIP or MOVETYPE_WALK)

    if(ply:KeyDown(IN_ATTACK2)) then
        ent:Freeze(true)
        RunCOnsoleCommand( "use", "keys" )
        ent:SetNWInt(GODMODE, 1)
        ent:DisallowSpawning( not should_unfreeze)
        ulx.setNoDie(ent, not should_unfreeze)
    else
        ent:Freeze(false)
        ent:SetNWInt(GODMODE, 0)
        ent:DisallowSpawning(false)
        ulx.setNoDie(ent, should_unfreeze)

        end
    if SERVER then if not ent:Alive() then
            ent:Spawn()
            self:PlayerSpawn(ent)
            ent:SetPos(ply:GetEyeTrace().HitPos)
        end
    end
    return
end
end)

    hook.Add("PhysgunPickup", "ply_frozen", function(pl, ent)
        if (ent:IsPlayer() )then
            ent._frozen = true
            print( "Entity is a player!" )
            RunConsoleCommand( "use", "keys")
        else
            print( "Entity is not a player!" )
            return false
        end
    end)

    function playerdies( ply, weapon, killer ) if(ply._frozen)then
        return false
    else
        return true
    end

hook.Add("CanPlayerSuicide", "playerNoDeath", playerDies)
    end
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does it make your computer spill coffee?

Comment: When I pick a player up it doesn't switch to keys and when I right click it doesn't freeze the player.